# Sublime Text 2 Key Bindings - Is there any way to detect left/right modifier keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, modifier-key

Is it possible to make <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> do different things? And of course, other modifier keys.

If not, maybe the following idea would work? 
If AppleScript, Python, Ruby, Perl etc. can detect left/right modifiers I can set complicated key bindings in sublime text (like ["cmd+ctrl+shift+alt+a", "cmd+ctrl+shift+alt+a"]) and send those keystrokes with AppleScript or Automator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sublime Text 2 does recognise right alt and left alt as separate modifiers.

Just refer to key bindings section of the documentation for the full rules: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings

Comment: I think those are for Sublime Text (not 2). But if 1 has it 2 should too, right?